# Internacionalización - Error a ejecutar "django-admin compilemessages"

Tags: django

¿Cual es el error? ¿Cómo se puede solucionar?
A veces sucede que tengo que traducir la misma palabra o frase varias veces en el mismo sitio web. No se si ese puede ser el problema. ¿Qué solución tiene?

**Error:**

**django-admin makemessages -l en**

```
CommandError: errors happened while running msgmerge
/home/Documents/proyect/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:121: duplicate message definition...
/home/Documents/proyect/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:32: ...this is the location of the first definition
msgmerge: found 1 fatal error
```

**django-admin makemessages -l eu**

```
CommandError: errors happened while running msgmerge
/home/retegi/Documents/proyect/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:121: duplicate message definition...
/home/retegi/Documents/proyect/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:32: ...this is the location of the first definition
msgmerge: found 1 fatal error
```

**en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po**

```
30 #: applications/home/templates/base.html:143
31 msgid "Cider houses"
32 msgstr "Cider houses"

118 #: applications/home/templates/home/home.html:207
119 #, fuzzy
120 #| msgid "Cider houses"
121 msgid "Cider houses"
122 msgstr "Cider houses"
```

**eu/LC_MESSAGES/django.po**

```
30 #: applications/home/templates/base.html:143
31 msgid "Cider houses"
32 msgstr "Sagardotegiak"

118 #: applications/home/templates/home/home.html:207
119 #, fuzzy
120 #| msgid "Cider houses"
121 msgid "Cider houses"
122 msgstr "Sagardotegiak"
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En cada archivo de traducción `.po` debería aparecer cada `msgid` una sola vez.
Si en tus fuentes utilizas "Cider houses", será traducido siempre como "Sagardotegiak", aunque lo hagas en diferentes zonas de tu web. Pero en el `.po` debe aparecer una sola vez.

Quítalo y fíjate cómo al hacer `makemessages` deberá salirte encima del `msgid` todos los sitios donde se utiliza.

Comment: Gracias Daniel. Sucede que si borro el que está repetido, al ejecutar de nuevo "django-admin makemessages -l eu" por ejemplo, se crea de nuevo el duplicado entonces me encuentro en la misma situación. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que no se duplique de nuevo? Gracias.

Comment: Al ejecutar `makemessages` después de borrar el duplicado, te genera algún tipo de error?